# I try to install express-generator, but I receive a curious error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've searched every SO question even closely related and everything I've tried hasn't worked. Any ideas? I can post the debug log, but it is quite long and I can't get it to format correctly. Let me know if this would be helpful.

~/desktop/node_tutorial $ npm install express-generator -g

npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express-generator" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/*****/Desktop/node_tutorial/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it wants you to be an administrator:

```
...
Please try running this command again as root/Administrator
...
```

Try `sudo npm install -g express-generator`

Comment: You're installing a tool that will create a new express app from the command line.  If you can do `express -h` you have it installed.  Here's some more info on how to use [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator)

Comment: Thanks. Why did this need sudo?

Comment: Sudo is often required when installing executable software on your machine.  You're essentially saying "I have admin access and I approve this software". [Li'l more info](https://kb.iu.edu/d/amyi)

Comment: @jro This command needs `sudo` because the `-g` flag installs the module globally to all projects/directories (root level), as opposed to only in a single project/directory (which is the default).